# Regular Expressions to restrict specific user input

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to restrict users to enter data in the form *Hello World*... I want to use regular expressions but I am not good at it.

My attempt was: `^([A-Z]{1})([a-z]{1,})([ ])?([A-Z]{1})?([a-z]{1,})?$`

For the groups starting at ([ ])? Are supposed to be optional...

For instance, the following are **valid** entries:

*Hello*, *Hello World*, *People*, *People Talk*

The following are **invalid:**

*people*, *people Talk*, *People talk*, *people talk*, *heLlo*

This `REGEX` would have to be case-sensative as the previous examples imply.

Comment: Consider [this](https://regex101.com/) tool

Comment: Does this do what you want? `^([A-Z]{1})([a-z]{1,})\s*(([A-Z]{1})+([a-z]{1,}))?$`

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a regular expression that matches a series of words where each word starts with a captial letter and the rest of the letters are lowercase?

Comment: `{1}` is never needed, that's the default for all expressions. `{1,}` can be replaced with `+`.

Comment: Since the space between the words is optional, this will allow `PeopleTalk`

Comment: I was not aware of Michele's tool above. The one I use is [regexr.com](https://regexr.com). I didn't compare the features..

Comment: @MicheleLambertucci No, it doesn't

Comment: @AdamP Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: @Barmar Oops! OK, the space should not be optional then... but it should only be added if there's another word coming ahead of it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the whole second word optional as a single group, rather than putting `?` after each part of it. Otherwise, the space between the words is optional, so you'll allow two words with no space between them, and the initial capital letter is optional, so you'll allow `Hello world`.

```
^[A-Z][a-z]+(\s[A-Z][a-z]+)?$
```

There's no need for `{1}` as patterns match a single time by default. `+` is normally used to match 1 or more of something, rather than `{1,}`. And `\s` matches any kind of whitespace.

And you need to anchor the regexp with `^` and `$` so the entire input has to match it.

Comment: Now this does what I wanted... Thank you!

Comment: As a note, the `?` at the end will only allow one or two words total. If you want more than that you may want to change it to either a `*` or a quantifier such as `{0,x}`.

Comment: By the way, how can I restrict an input to accept exactly what I specify in the regular expression? I mean, I want *Someone* to be typed literally as it is.